# Does every browser open a new HTTPSession

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am working on a webbased application which has JSP and servlets. In my application, I am binding some objects to sessions like the following code --

```
HttpSession session = p_req.getSession();        
 session.setAttribute(DOWNLOAD_With_WARNINGS, downloadMap);
```

Later I am retrieving them using session.getAttribute. I would like to know if every time I open a new browser does it open a new HTTP session. Because , if I do a `setAttribute` with some value in one browser instance, that change is visible when I do a `getAttribute` using the other browser instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour depends on browsers.

IE 6 - Everytime you open a new browser window, you'll have a new session. But if you open a new window using File - New menu, it will use the same session.

All the other browsers - Opening a new browser window will use the existing session.

To be sure, clear your cookies once.